# How I can use EX4 with an attribute containing dash character?

Tags: javascript, xml, apache-flex, actionscript, e4x

Having this code

```
var images:XML = 
    <elements>
        <el data-custom="abc"/>
        <el data-custom="def"/>
        <el data-custom="ghi"/>
    </elements>
```

How can i get attributes value with an e4x expression? Please note the dash "-" character in the attribute name. I use it in Flex but it could be a general question for the E4X standard.

You can't obviously use:

```
 trace(elements.el.@data-custom)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some not so easy search I found an answer for the posterity

```
elements.el.@['data-custom'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In numerous occasions I prefer using the [attribute()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#attribute%28%29) method of XML/XMLList instead of the (@) identifier. It also works with the attribute names that are also reserved Actionscript words like "class","package", "return",etc...